# ASP.NET WebApi call for 401 gets changed to 303 -> 400

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cloudflare

On localhost, an unauthorized request to web api (using OAuth) correctly returns a 401 response.  However, when we push to the test (or qa/prod) server, it ends up doing a 303 and then a 400 with this url:

/error/400.html?al_req_id=WMv8BMFouUYAAAPyFZ0AAATw

My gut tells me that either AppShield or CloudFlare is catching this 401 error and doing this redirect, but I can't seem to verify it.  Has anyone else ever had this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Some more information.  We are using OWIN Katana on .NET 4.5 (not Core).

Comment: Most CDNs are configured to ignore query string by default. Can you enable forwarding query string and then try?

Comment: What kind of setup have you got on your server? I wonder if there is some kind of internal redirect going on? Do you get the 303 for other API calls?

Comment: It isn't a CDN.  It is an Api end point.  The server is behind AppShiled using CloudFlare.  It only gives me a 303 -> 400 when the request is invalid somehow. i.e. Invalid or expired OAuth token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that IIS had something configured that was intercepting for 401s and did a 303 -> 400.